# Returning values from a C++ program into a bash script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, batch-file, return-value

I have a C++ program (on Linux) that computes a double result, and I want to write a bash script that runs the program a variable number of times and averages these results for me.  For simplicity, consider the following code:

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Some other stuff\n";

    double result = foo();

    return 0;
}
```

script.sh:

```
sum = 0
num = $1
for((i = 0; i < $num; i++)); do
    result = ./a.out;  #store the result somehow?
    sum = $sum + $result
done
avg = $sum / $num
echo "Average: " $avg
```

Is there an easy way to pass the result of the program back into the bash script?  I read about using the exit code, but the return type is a double so I don't think that will work.  Parsing the value from string output is unwieldy because the program has other terminal output.

Comment: The return code must be an integer - there is no way around it. You can write the result to the special file and then read this file with bash.

Comment: The standard approach to transferring data between programs in a Unix environment is via standard output and standard input. Print your output.

Comment: One option is to scale all your outputs by some factor (like 1000), cast to `int` and `return` then down-scale them in the script by the same factor.

Comment: So, do I have to "give up" all the other text output from the program to avoid having to manually parse through for the desired value?  (There are a few other numerical results that are not the desired value that are still printed to console for reference)

Comment: Consider the "upscale/downscale" mechanism if you want to keep your existing text output; note that scaling and truncation comes with automatic data loss.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The UNIX way of doing this is writing non-essential data on stderr and writing the actual result on stdout. That way, you can simply do

```
int main() {
    cerr << "This is output that won't be captured." << endl;
    cout << "3.141592" << endl; 
}
```

and use command substitution to capture it:

```
result=$(./a.out)
```

An uglier way of doing that doesn't require changing the output is to write to another file descriptor:

```
int main() { 
    char* foo = "3.141592\n";
    write(42, foo, strlen(foo));
}
```

This will let you capture the output with:

```
result=$(./a.out 42>&1 > /dev/null)
```

Note that your shell script has several syntax errors. Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) to automatically sort out many of them, and feel free to post a question about the issues you can't resolve.

Comment: "the program has other terminal output."

Comment: Thanks!  I wound up using command line arguments to switch between batch file output and verbose terminal output.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use return value as data to your bash script?

```
int main() {
        return 46;
}
```

The output is as follows (yes, it's bash script):

```
./a.out ; echo $?
46
```

In case of double values you could use this approach:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        double res = 46.001;
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
a=`./a.out`; echo $a
46.001
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is limited to an 8 bit integer, and won't work with the double donnyton wants to return.

Comment: "Parsing the value from string output is unwieldy because the program has other terminal output."